# IndexError: list index out of range / AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

[image]

I am trying to **scrape** like/views from instagram. however getting error below:

IndexError: list index out of range :--- `when i try viewcth[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')`

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' :---  when i try  `viewct = viewcth.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

code:

```
viewcth = bdy.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='EDfFK ygqzn']//*[@class='Nm9Fw']")
if (len(viewcth) != 0):
    viewct = viewcth[0].get_attribute('innerText')
else:
    viewcth = bdy.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='HbPOm _9Ytll']//*[@class='vcOH2']")
    # viewct = viewcth.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    viewct = viewcth[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
pagedict['viewcount'] = viewct
print("Viewct is " + viewct)
```

Comment: What is confusing about the two errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
This is why `viewcth` is and empty list.
`find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='EDfFK ygqzn']//*[@class='Nm9Fw']")` finds no matching elements and returns empty list.
So when you trying to get a first element from that list by `viewcth[0]` you are getting

> `IndexError: list index out of range`.

If you trying to perform `viewct = viewcth.get_attribute('innerHTML')` this gives you

> `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`

since `viewcth` is a list. Empty, but still a list.
So you can not apply `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` method on a list, it is not a web element.
If you want to get amount of like try this:
For images

```
likes = bdy.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='zV_Nj']/span").text
```

For videos:

```
likes = bdy.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='Nm9Fw']/a").text
```

Or

```
likes = bdy.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='HbPOm _9Ytll']/span").text
```

Comment: it is giving AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. i have tried this ->     bdy = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_9eogI E3X2T']//*[@class='SCxLW  o64aR ']//*[@class='ltEKP']")
    img = bdy.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='_97aPb wKWK0']//*[@class='KL4Bh']//img")

    likes = bdy.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@class='zV_Nj']/span").text
    print(likes)

Comment: Do you mean the `likes = bdy.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='zV_Nj']/span").text` ? I just fixed it, sorry, my typo

Comment: this is working for image post but for video or reel post no luck !

Comment: OK, will give you locators for them too, moment. can you give me some links to video and reel pages?

Comment: I have added more options. If there are still page you can't find a locator for likes - please let me know

Answer (score 1):

See `viewcth` is a list in Python.

and you have stated this  :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' :---
> when i try viewct = viewcth.get_attribute('innerHTML')

so when you can not use `get_attribute()` on list. But in your code I see, you have not used `viewcth.get_attribute('innerHTML')` instead it is

```
viewcth[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

which is right I think.

I have used a counter, to count total comment.

**sample code  :**

```
counter = 0
viewcth = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='EDfFK ygqzn']//*[@class='Nm9Fw']")
if (len(viewcth) != 0):
    abc = viewcth[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    counter = counter  + 1
else:
    viewcth2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='HbPOm _9Ytll']//*[@class='vcOH2']")
    cde = viewcth2[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    counter = counter + 1

print("total view  is ",  counter)
```

**Update 1 :**

You can try the below xpath :

to get only numbers :

```
//textarea/ancestor::section/preceding-sibling::section[1]/descendant::span
```

**code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
print(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea/ancestor::section/preceding-sibling::section[1]/descendant::span"))).text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: still giving error ->     cde = viewcth2[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: that means that list `viewcth2` does not have a any element in it. Are you sure if this is the right path `.//*[@class='eo2As ']//*[@class='HbPOm _9Ytll']//*[@class='vcOH2']` ?

Comment: yes i guess . you can refer above screenshot.

Comment: I would probably write a custom locator and give it to you. Just give me some time

Comment: @pkk : Can you try with the above xpath ? let me know if there's any issue

Comment: the above updated 1 code is just for single post, to check the number of likes. if it works fully then we can try to loop it for all the post if that is what you are looking for